# Explain why twice the sum $\binom{12}{0} + \binom{12}{1} + \binom{12}{2} + \binom{12}{3} + \binom{12}{4} + \binom{12}{5}$ is $2^{12}-\binom{12}6$

Tags: binomial-coefficients

Can someone explain how is the RHS concluded? I did with sample numbers and it is all correct. but I can't figure out how C(12,6) comes to play.
$$
\binom{12}{0} + \binom{12}{1} + \binom{12}{2} + \binom{12}{3} + \binom{12}{4} + \binom{12}{5} = (2^{12} - \binom{12}{6}) / 2
$$

Comment: Do you know the value of
$$C(12,0) + C(12,1) + ... + C(12,12)$$
??

Comment: Yes, it is. C(12,0)+C(12,1)+...+C(12,12) = 2^12

Comment: Right. Now using the hint in Yikai's answer, if
$$ x = C(12,0) + ... + C(12,5)$$
$$ y = C(12,12) + ... + C(12,7)$$
how do $x,y$ compare?

Comment: I see that x = y (I am not really good in maths :( )

Comment: So, if you subtract $C(12,6)$ from $2^{12}$, what's left?

Comment: When I subtract C(12,6), I have 2x (or 2y)s.

Comment: So, now you have it. Done!

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** We have
$$
\sum_{i=0}^n \binom{n}{i} = 2^n
$$
and
$$
\binom{n}{i} = \binom{n}{n-i}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Suppose we toss a fair coin for $12$ times. The number of combinations is $2^{12}$.

Now notice the number of outcomes $N(H>T)$ such that the total number of Head is more than Tail is same as that of Tail more than Head $N(H<T)$, by symmetry.

We know $N(H>T)$ is the total number of choosing less than $6$ Tails, which is 
$$N=\binom{12}{0} + \binom{12}{1} + \binom{12}{2} + \binom{12}{3} + \binom{12}{4} + \binom{12}{5}$$

We know that the no. of outcomes when the number of Head and Tail equals is ${12}\choose{6}$.

Since the total number of possible outcome is 
$$2N+{{12}\choose{6}}=2^{12}$$

The claim follows.

Comment: This is also a nice explanation. Thank you everyone!